# Work out the values of a and b in the identity $3ax + 6 - 4(x + b) = 11x + 14$

Tags: calculus

The = is supposed to be $3$ lines as it is supposed to be an identity.

Comment: want you solve the equation $$3ax+6-4(x+b)=11x+14$$ for $x$?

Comment: So.... do it.  What's your question?.  Where are you having trouble?  What do a and b have to be to make that an identity question?  Is it a conceptual problem you are having.?  The actual math is trivially easy.

Answer (score 2):

$3ax + 6 - 4(x+b) = $

$(3a-4)x + (6-4b) = 11x + 14$

So $3a - 4 = 11$ and $6-4b = 14$.  Solve for  $a$ and $b$.